# Is there a breaking change in angular when upgrading from angular 8 to 9 in nativeElement

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have recently upgraded my angular cli version to 9.1.4 from earlier version of 8. 
So i wanted to ask that is there a breaking change in this nativeElement thing.

Some of the code of my ts file where i used my nativeElement is as follows

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-note-card',
  templateUrl: './note-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./note-card.component.scss']
})
export class NoteCardComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() body: string;

  @ViewChild('truncator') truncator: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ViewChild('bodyText') bodyText:ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }



ngOnInit() {

    // work out if there is a text overflow and if not then hide the truncator

    let style = window.getComputedStyle(this.bodyText.nativeElement, null);
    let viewableHeight = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("height"), 10);

    if(this.bodyText.nativeElement.scrollHeight>viewableHeight){
      // if there is a text overflow, show the fade out truncator
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.truncator.nativeElement, 'display', 'block');
    }else{
      // else (there is a text overflow), hide the fade out truncator
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.truncator.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    }
  }

}
```

And this is the error which i get in the browser

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at NoteCardComponent.ngOnInit (note-card.component.ts:22)
    at callHook (core.js:4735)
    at callHooks (core.js:4699)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4639)
    at selectIndexInternal (core.js:9701)
    at Module.ɵɵadvance (core.js:9662)
    at NotesListComponent_Template (notes-list.component.html:19)
    at executeTemplate (core.js:12098)
    at refreshView (core.js:11945)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:13410)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:6237
```

Any help is welcomed Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try moving everything you have in the `ngOnInit` life cycle hook to an `ngAfterViewInit`  life cycle hook. https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `ViewChild` decorator in `OnInit` life cycle hook you must specify the `static` property to be true to resolve query results before change detection runs. By default is `false` so it resolves after change detection runs.

For use in `ngOnInit`, like in your case, see the code below:

```
  @ViewChild('truncator', { static: true }) truncator: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
  @ViewChild('bodyText', { static: true }) bodyText:ElementRef<HTMLElement>;
```

If you are not using in `OnInit` you need to set it to false. In Angular 9 is optional in this case since the default is false.

I wonder, how did you not get the errors in Angular 8 where this property was mandatory for both cases.

Answer (score 0):

`@ViewChild()` decorator makes the queried elements available only from `AfterViewInit` on. So, instead of running your code in `ngOnInit` method, move it to `ngAfterViewInit` method.